# In the new Firebase console I can't edit data at the root of the realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have several projects on firebase, all migrated to the new console.
In one of them I can't edit data in the console when I'm on some levels.

On deeper levels it works just fine...

Does it happen to anyone else?

Adding screenshots:
[image: hovering with no option to edit]
[image: hovering with no option to edit]

By puf:
[image: hovering with option to edit]

Comment: I've never seen this before. It can't be a permissions issue, since when you're in the console you are an administrator. Can you show a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Added. Tell me if you need anything else

Comment: Thanks for that. Are you looking to change the name of `teams` or a specific team?

Comment: Adding teams. All branches are not accessible when I'm in the root view and one other child view.

Comment: When I click to go deeper in the tree it works as expected and as any other project. One more thing that happens is when I click the root it takes me back to my projects list page. No immediate obvious errors in the console. Tell me if it'll help if I (privately) send you the project's id

Comment: I added a screenshot showing what you're supposed to see. What browser are you using?

Comment: I know what I'm supposed to see. I see it just fine on other projects and on deeper branches of this one (like if I click teams so the view changes as if teams is the root, all works fine). Working on Chrome 50. Same for Chrome on Android, Mac, and Windows

Comment: Any news? Is there some way I can contact you / support directly? Maybe you can check on a deeper level when having the project's ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase now adds the reason it happens:

[image]

That "solves" the issue for me, I truely have plenty of data in there.